# formatting Double class in a TextView

Tags: java, android, class, format, string-formatting

I create a static class named `Box`, and there I calculate the parameter `double AverageWeight`.

Then, in my `MainActivity`, I would like to print the result in a `TextView`, and show only two digit after decimal. How do I do that?

I've searched this question on Stack Overflow but I haven't found anything that referred to formatting Double class, and nothing I've tried worked.

```
//Convert the output from double to String
String avgWeight = Double.toString(Box.getAverageWeight());

//Set the String output to TextView
tv_resAvgWeight.setText(avgWeight);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Java `DecimalFormat` class, for example:

```
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
double d = 1.234242424;
System.out.println(format.format(d));
```

You can read the [full documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html) of the class for all the options that are available.